# HTML escribir etiquetas HTML comentadas dentro de un parrafo

Tags: html5

Necesito escribir un texto con las etiquetas de apertura y cierre de script dentro de un parrafo para indicar que se tienen que incluir en el textarea siguiente.

Si escribo lo siguiente:

**Incluir el Script entre etiquetas '< script type="text/javascript" >...< /script >'**

Pero para que no se muestren como etiquetas, he tenido que introducir un espacio delante de **script** para que no lo interprete como etiqueta HTML.

¿Existe alguna manera de hacerlo para no incluir el espacio de delante?

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa las entidades HTML, por ejemplo, < es &lt; y > es &gt;

```
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

Consulta:
https://www.manualweb.net/html/entidades-html/

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona